# Pegar o id via URL no JS enviado por PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho um código que joga um ID no HTML para um link:

```
<a href="javascript:confirmacao(<?php echo $row['idfoto'] ?>)"> <i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
```

Já no JavaScript tenho o código que chama o arquivo `delete.php`, que pega o ID.

```
function confirmacao(id) {
var resposta = confirm("Tem certeza que deseja remover essa informação?");

if (resposta == true) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/delete.php?delete_id=' + id,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (data) {
        $.get("/read.php", {}, function (data, status) {
            $('.read_content').html(data);
        });
    });
}
}
```

Fiz uma modificação e criei uma função dentro do `ready` do jQuery como acima, que está dando esse erro quando clico no link.

> VM499:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: confirmacao is not defined
>       at :1:1
>   (anonymous) @ VM499:1

Está falando que a função não está definida, será que tem algo a vê com o jQuery?

Comment: A função precisa ser declarada no escopo global para ser chamada da maneira como você fez. E no seu código deve estar no escopo de um handler de load/ready do jq.

Comment: Ela está dentro de `$(document).ready(function () { }`

Comment: Então, exatamente o que pensei, precisa tirar daí e deixar no escopo global.

Comment: Tem alguma forma de mudar essa função e para que ela fique dentro do escopo do ready assim do JQuery?

Comment: Se ela estiver no escopo global ela também vai estar no escopo do ready. só mova ela para fora.

Comment: Só tem um problema, não sei se por conta de está fora de escopo, o $.get não está funcionando para exibir os dados na div e atualizando as informações.